# Trouble Installing Matplotlib on Python 3.4

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, pip

I tried to install matplotlib by following this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-llHYUMH9Dg

I followed everything EXACTLY. It was working until I tried

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install matplotlib
```

I then received this error message

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\KIEFER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kai2npum\matplotlib

I have no idea what to do. I just finished Codeacademy and I am wanting to move onto learning matplotlib.

I am very grateful for any help anyone can give, even if someone can point me in the right direction. I'm not asking to be spoon fed.

This is the full error message.

C:\Python34\Scripts>cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-1.5.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

```
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.5.2]
                python: yes [3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015,
                        19:28:18) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]]
              platform: yes [win32]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.11.1]
              dateutil: yes [dateutil was not found. It is required for date
                        axis support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                  pytz: yes [pytz was not found. pip will attempt to install
                        it after matplotlib.]
                cycler: yes [cycler was not found. pip will attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
               tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                        WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
             pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                        mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype (ft2build.h)
                        could not be found.  You may need to install the
                        development package.]
                   png: no  [The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be
                        found.  You may need to install the development
                        package.]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                        found. Using local copy.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                        matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
                        your preferred tool to run the test suite / using
                        unittest.mock]
        toolkits_tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                        matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
                        your preferred tool to run the test suite / using
                        unittest.mock]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
                qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
               gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                 tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                        Tk]
                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                   gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                   agg: yes [installing]
                 cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
             windowing: yes [installing]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: no
           ghostscript: no
                 latex: no
               pdftops: no

OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                  dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

============================================================================
                        * The following required packages can not be built:
                        * freetype, png

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\KIEFER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-nhz_3wzz\matplotlib
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Python34\Scripts>

Comment: Use [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#anaconda-for-windows-install)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That is not super helpful.

Comment: @mrs_robot Can you post the full error message?

Comment: @tcaswell thanks for the hasty reply. i just added the full error message to my post. What're the benefits of anaconda over installing matplotlib? thanks